# "Better" enumeration for C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, enum

I've been looking to have "smarter" or "better" enum functionality in C#. There are a few GitHub/NuGet projects out there, but they seem to target newer versions of .NET and I wanted this to be able to work with Framework 4.6 and newer - so it's in a NetStandard 2.0 library. The feature set is similar to enums but without Flags support. It can support descriptions natively, import from existing enums, convert back and forth to underlying types, etc. No formalized tests yet, but I thought I'd start by soliciting some feedback.

We start with the base class, which is intended to hold most of the boilerplate functionality:

```
namespace EnumerationClasses
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Text;

    public abstract class Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>, IComparable<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IEnumeration<TValue>
        where TEnumeration : Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>
        where TValue : struct, IComparable, IConvertible
    {
        private static readonly ISet<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>> _Enums =
            new HashSet<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>();

        static Enumeration() => RunClassConstructors();

        protected Enumeration()
        {
        }

        protected Enumeration(string name, TValue? value = null, string description = null)
        {
            if (name is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be empty or only whitespace.", nameof(name));
            }

            lock (_Enums)
            {
                if (_Enums.Any(@enum => @enum.Name == name))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Name '{name}' already exists for this enumeration.", nameof(name));
                }

                this.Name = name;
                this.Value = GetValue(value);
                this.Description = description ?? this.GetDescription();
                _Enums.Add(this);
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; }

        public TValue Value { get; }

        public string Description { get; }

        public static implicit operator TValue(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> enumerationItem) =>
            enumerationItem?.Value ?? default(TValue);

        public static explicit operator Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>(TValue value) => FromValue(value);

        public static bool operator ==(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> left, Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> right) =>
            EqualityComparer<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>.Default.Equals(left, right);

        public static bool operator !=(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> left, Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> right) =>
            !EqualityComparer<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>.Default.Equals(left, right);

        public static bool operator <(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> left, Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> right) =>
            Comparer<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>.Default.Compare(left, right) < 0;

        public static bool operator >(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> left, Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> right) =>
            Comparer<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>.Default.Compare(left, right) > 0;

        public static bool operator <=(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> left, Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> right) =>
            Comparer<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>.Default.Compare(left, right) <= 0;

        public static bool operator >=(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> left, Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> right) =>
            Comparer<Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>>.Default.Compare(left, right) >= 0;

        public static void CreateFromEnum<TEnumType>()
            where TEnumType : struct
        {
            ConstructorInfo constructor =
                typeof(TEnumeration).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(TValue), typeof(string) });

            if (constructor is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Create();

            void Create()
            {
                foreach (TEnumType @enum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnumType)).Cast<TEnumType>())
                {
                    _ = constructor.Invoke(
                        new object[]
                        {
                            @enum.ToString(),
                            (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(@enum, typeof(TValue)),
                            GetDescription((Enum)(object)@enum),
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TEnumeration> GetAll()
        {
            lock (_Enums)
            {
                return _Enums.OrderBy(@enum => @enum.Value).ThenBy(@enum => @enum.Name).Cast<TEnumeration>().ToList();
            }
        }

        public static TEnumeration FromName(string name) =>
            Parse(name, nameof(name), item => item.Name == name);

        public static TValue? ValueFromName(string name) =>
            Parse(name, nameof(name), item => item.Name == name)?.Value;

        public static string DescriptionFromName(string name) =>
            Parse(name, nameof(name), item => item.Name == name)?.Description;

        public static TEnumeration FromValue(TValue value) =>
            Parse(value, nameof(value), item => item.Value.CompareTo(value) == 0);

        public static string NameFromValue(TValue value) =>
            Parse(value, nameof(value), item => item.Value.CompareTo(value) == 0)?.Name;

        public static string DescriptionFromValue(TValue value) =>
            Parse(value, nameof(value), item => item.Value.CompareTo(value) == 0)?.Description;

        public int CompareTo(object obj) => obj is Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> other
            ? this.CompareTo(other)
            : throw new ArgumentException($"Object must be of type {this.GetType().Name}", nameof(obj));

        public int CompareTo(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (other is null)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
            obj is Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> otherValue && this.Equals(otherValue);

        public bool Equals(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> x, Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> y) =>
            x?.Equals(y) == true;

        public override int GetHashCode() => this.GetHashCode(this);

        public int GetHashCode(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> obj) => obj?.Value.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        public override string ToString() => this.Name;

        public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider) => this.ToString();

        [Obsolete("The provider argument is not used. Please use ToString(String).")]
        public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) => this.ToString(format);

        public string ToString(string format)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
            {
                format = "G";
            }

            if (string.Equals(format, "G", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return this.ToString();
            }

            return string.Equals(format, "D", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                ? this.Value.ToString()
                : throw new FormatException($"{nameof(format)} contains an invalid specification.");
        }

        public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
        {
            Type underlyingType = this.Value.GetType();

            if (underlyingType == typeof(int))
            {
                return TypeCode.Int32;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(sbyte))
            {
                return TypeCode.SByte;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(short))
            {
                return TypeCode.Int16;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(long))
            {
                return TypeCode.Int64;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(uint))
            {
                return TypeCode.UInt32;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(byte))
            {
                return TypeCode.Byte;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(ushort))
            {
                return TypeCode.UInt16;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(ulong))
            {
                return TypeCode.UInt64;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(bool))
            {
                return TypeCode.Boolean;
            }

            if (underlyingType == typeof(char))
            {
                return TypeCode.Char;
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("The enumeration type is unknown.");
        }

        bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToBoolean(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        char IConvertible.ToChar(IFormatProvider provider) => Convert.ToChar(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToSByte(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        byte IConvertible.ToByte(IFormatProvider provider) => Convert.ToByte(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        short IConvertible.ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToInt16(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        ushort IConvertible.ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToUInt16(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        int IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) => Convert.ToInt32(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        uint IConvertible.ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToUInt32(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        long IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider) => Convert.ToInt64(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        ulong IConvertible.ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToUInt64(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        float IConvertible.ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToSingle(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        double IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToDouble(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ToDecimal(this.Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        DateTime IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider) =>
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot convert a {this.GetType()} to a {nameof(DateTime)}.");

        object IConvertible.ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) =>
            Convert.ChangeType(this.Value, conversionType);

        private static void RunClassConstructors()
        {
            foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                RunClassConstructors(assembly);
            }
        }

        private static void RunClassConstructors(Assembly assembly)
        {
            if (assembly is null || !AssemblyTracker.SeenAssemblies.Add(assembly))
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type != typeof(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>)
                && typeof(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue>).IsAssignableFrom(type)))
            {
                RunClassConstructorSafely(type.TypeHandle);
            }

            foreach (AssemblyName assemblyName in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                RunClassConstructors(Assembly.Load(assemblyName));
            }
        }

        private static void RunClassConstructorSafely(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle)
        {
            try
            {
                RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeHandle);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        private static TValue GetValue(TValue? value = null) => value ?? (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(
            _Enums.Any()
                ? _Enums.Max(@enum => @enum.Value.ToUInt64(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) + 1UL
                : 0UL,
            typeof(TValue));

        private static TEnumeration Parse<TSearchValue>(
            TSearchValue value,
            string nameOrValue,
            Func<TEnumeration, bool> predicate) =>
            GetAll().FirstOrDefault(predicate)
            ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{value}' is not a valid {nameOrValue} in {typeof(TEnumeration)}");

        private static string GetDescription(Enum enumType) => BuildDescription(enumType
            .GetType()
            .GetField(enumType.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>());

        private static string BuildDescription(IEnumerable<DescriptionAttribute> descriptionAttributes)
        {
            if (descriptionAttributes?.Any() != true)
            {
                return null;
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            bool notFirst = false;

            foreach (DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute in descriptionAttributes)
            {
                if (notFirst)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }

                sb.Append(descriptionAttribute.Description);
                notFirst = true;
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static MemberInfo GetMember(string name, Type type)
        {
            while (type is object)
            {
                MemberInfo member = type.GetProperty(name) ?? (MemberInfo)type.GetField(name);

                if (member is object)
                {
                    return member;
                }

                type = type.BaseType;
            }

            return null;
        }

        private bool Equals(Enumeration<TEnumeration, TValue> other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (other is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.Value.Equals(other.Value);
        }

        private string GetDescription()
        {
            string name = this.ToString();
            MemberInfo memberInfo = GetMember(name, this.GetType());
            IEnumerable<DescriptionAttribute> descriptionAttributes =
                memberInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false).Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                ?? Enumerable.Empty<DescriptionAttribute>();
            string description = BuildDescription(descriptionAttributes);

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)
                ? EnumNameParser.EnumName.Replace(name, " $1").Trim()
                : description;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a typical use case. Static fields or properties with name/value and optional descriptions. This example also uses subclassing for having business logic tied to the enumeration type itself rather than be in a `switch` statement elsewhere.

```
namespace EnumerationClasses.Domain
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public abstract class EmployeeType : Enumeration<EmployeeType, int>
    {
        [Description("Assistant to the Regional Manager")]
        public static readonly EmployeeType AssistantToTheRegionalManager2 =
            new StandardEmployeeType(nameof(AssistantToTheRegionalManager2));

        private EmployeeType()
        {
        }

        private EmployeeType(string name, int? value = null, string description = null)
            : base(name, value, description)
        {
        }

        [Description("Head Honcho")]
        public static EmployeeType Manager { get; } = new ManagerType(nameof(Manager), 1);

        [Description("Serf")]
        public static EmployeeType Servant { get; } = new StandardEmployeeType(nameof(Servant), 2);

        [Description("Assistant to the Regional Manager")]
        public static EmployeeType AssistantToTheRegionalManager { get; } =
            new StandardEmployeeType(nameof(AssistantToTheRegionalManager), description: "Lesser Serf");

        public abstract decimal BonusAmount { get; }

        private sealed class ManagerType : EmployeeType
        {
            public ManagerType(string name, int? value = null, string description = null)
                : base(name, value, description)
            {
            }

            private ManagerType()
            {
            }

            public override decimal BonusAmount => 15000.00M;
        }

        private sealed class StandardEmployeeType : EmployeeType
        {
            public StandardEmployeeType(string name, int? value = null, string description = null)
                : base(name, value, description)
            {
            }

            private StandardEmployeeType()
            {
            }

            public override decimal BonusAmount => 1000.00M;
        }
    }
}
```

A quick little example/test of how to enumerate over all the employees created:

```
foreach (EmployeeType employee in Enumeration<EmployeeType, int>.GetAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{employee.Name} {employee.Value} ({employee.Description}): {employee.BonusAmount:C}");
}
```

Here is another example of dynamically adding enumeration items to an enumeration, this time importing them from a "classic" enum:

```
namespace EnumerationClasses.Domain
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public enum PaymentTypeOld
    {
        Unknown,

        [Description("Cold, hard, American Dollars")]
        Cash,

        Credit,

        Lease,
    }
}

namespace EnumerationClasses.Domain
{
    public sealed class PaymentTypeNew : Enumeration<PaymentTypeNew, int>
    {
        public PaymentTypeNew(string name, int? value = null, string description = null)
            : base(name, value, description)
        {
        }

        private PaymentTypeNew()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And some quick example code to populate and then iterate:

```
Enumeration<PaymentTypeNew, int>.CreateFromEnum<PaymentTypeOld>();
foreach (IEnumeration<int> newStyleEnum in Enumeration<PaymentTypeNew, int>.GetAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{newStyleEnum.Name} {newStyleEnum.Value} ({newStyleEnum.Description})");
}
```

The code I've posted has also removed a bunch of XML documentation to be space-conscious.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it how is it "smarter" or "better" than enum?

Comment: @PeterCsala well, I do suppose smarter and better are subjective terms, but the gist is to have the functionality of enums but with the opportunity to use the OOP and functionality that actual classes allow where enums do not. My particular example centralizes domain logic where it would have to exist elsewhere with enums. So, YMMV in usage/need.

Comment: So many lines of super smart code and silly me would just add an extension method to `Enum<T>` that uses reflection to get the Description and return `IEnumerable<NameDescriptionAndValueDto>`and call it a day. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388072/how-to-add-extension-methods-to-enums I could also make the `NameDescriptionAndValueDto` a record so it works as a value object. You can use Records in .NET Framework. https://blog.ndepend.com/using-c9-record-and-init-property-in-your-net-framework-4-x-net-standard-and-net-core-projects/

Comment: @FilipFranik yep, I cannibalized the description code from an extension method I had put together for enums - probably used a bit of the code from one of the answers on that question a decade ago.